# What is the advantage of using OData with Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am already using the standard WebAPI and returning JSON objects to my client. Now I saw an application that returned OData.

Can someone explain if there is any reason for me to use OData if I do not want to query my data from anything other than my own client running in the browser. Are there advantages that I could get through using OData ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are only using your data in your own browser application, there is only few advantages to use OData in your situation:

1. OData is able to provide metadata about your service interface that can be used to generate client code to access the service. So if you have lots of client classes that you need to create, this could speed up your process. On the other hand, if you can share your classes between the server and an ASP.NET based client or if you only have a few classes, this might not be relevant in your situation.
2. Another - bigger - advantage in your situation is the support for generic queries against the service data. OData supports `IQueryable` so that you can decide on the client side on how to filter the data that the service provides. So you do not have to implement various actions or use query parameters to provide filtered data. This also means that if you need a new filter for your client, it is very likely that you do not have to change the server and can just put up the query on the client side. Possible filters include $filter expressions to filter the data, but also operations like $skip and $top that are useful when paging data. For details on OData and queries, see this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options).

For a complete overview about OData and Web API see this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "OData is able to provide metadata about your service interface that can be used to generate client code to access the service."

Comment: @Melina: metadata describe the structure of the data that your service provides. If you do not reuse the same classes as the service does in the client and if you do not want to create the classes on the client manually, you can use these metadata to generate classes that match the structure of the classes of the service. This simplifies access to the service a lot - especially for other developers. But this might not be relevant for you as you are the only user of the service.

Comment: @Melina: I've updated my answer with another advantage and a link to some good tutorials if you want to check out OData and Web API.

Comment: What about non-open data, ie, restricting data by user permissions? It seems that when using OData the server coding work is reversed -- everything is possible to query, and we must work to close of what certain users shouldn't be able to access/modify/delete. Yes? Or?

Comment: @mylord: OData does not differ too much from a standard web api in that sense. In a standard web api you'd also have to restrict access to controllers or actions by using the 'Authorize' attribute. If you want to have fine-grained control and filter the data by user permissions, you'd have to apply this filter in the controller actions anyway.

Comment: @Markus I haven't used 'Authorize' yet, but I have a non OData API to GetList(MyCriteria c), and then, based on c, I return something. However, with OData, all I have to do is link up DB table relations and I can offer all possible queries, but then I have to work to restrict those, rather than start with nothing and build only the queries I want to allow for criteria c. And, I have to deal with an extra layer (OData). If my data is truly open to all, OData seems like a huge benefit. Otherwise, I don't see it. I'm here to understand if and how I'm wrong.

Comment: @mylord: the easy way to implement an OData controller is to link the controller to the tables directly, e.g. by using an Entity Framework model without adding too much code. There are some basic filter options, but not too many. You can also implement the OData controller without this direct integration and add some more sophisticated filter options. See this link for details: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

Comment: [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/work-with-odata-in-web-api-understand-odata-in-web-api/) is **another article** , may help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few advantages of OData.

1. OData is a open protocol started by Microsoft is based on Rest Services so we can get data base on URL.
2. It suppport various protocol like http,atom,pub and also support JSON format.
3. No need to create proxy classes which we used to do it in web service.
4. You will able to write your own custom methods.
5. It is very light weight so the interaction between client and server will be fast compared to web service and other technologies.
6. Very simple to use.

Here are few reference links.

http://sandippatilprogrammer.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/what-is-odata-advantages-and-disadvantages/

http://geekswithblogs.net/venknar/archive/2010/07/08/introduction-odata.aspx

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/why-microsofts-open-data-protocol-matters/12700

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "No need to create proxy classes which we used to do it in web service" and also "It is very light weight so the interaction between client and server will be fast compared to web service and other technologies". Are you saying it is faster than if I use ASP.Net Web API ?

Comment: when you use web service of wcf service either you need to add web reference for web service or service reference for WCF Service. So that will create a proxy class to call that web service. While with odata you don't have to add any reference from URL you can perform things.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers already posted, but as an additional insight...

You mentioned that:

> ... if I do not want to query my data from anything other than my own
>   client running in the browser...

You may not wish to run it *normally* through anything but your own cilent, but using oData you could use other querying tools for debugging. For example [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) allows you to use oData endpoints (such as that provided by stackoverflow).

It's probably not a good enough reason to implement oData if you don't have another reason to do so, but it's an added bonus.